# soap_envelope_1__1.Fault detail node

Tags: xml, xslt, biztalk

I'm catching a fault of type soap_envelope_1__1.Fault.

I receive the following code back when I run debug mode and get the fault that comes back

```
<soapenv:Fault xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <faultcode>soapenv:Server</faultcode>
    <faultstring>Missing or Invalid Information</faultstring>
    <detail>
        <ns3:sendFault xmlns:ns3="http://thisservice.com/was/v1" xmlns:ns2="http://thisservice.com/pos/v1" xmlns:ns4="http://thisservice.com/lr/v1" xmlns:ns5="http://thisservice.com/dl/v1" xmlns:ns6="http://thisservice.com/ted/v1" xmlns:ns7="http://thisservice.com/header/v1">
            <code>Actual_Code_18</code>
            <info>Bad Information</info>
        </ns3:sendFault>
    </detail>
</soapenv:Fault>
```

For my send port im using a Wcf-BasicHTTPPort with inbound messagebody set to body, and propagate fault message checked.

in my orchestration I have the fault set for soap_envelope_1__1.Fault.
my catch in the scope shape receives the fault. 
In a construct message shape I construct object generated by the fault to my fault message: Message_myFault = myFault;

then I use an xslt map to map the code and info tags from my fault message. My problem is I cannot seem to find the right xpath for the INFO and CODE Tags, they come out blank in my message, but if I use faultcode or faultstring it fills.
heres the piece: `<xsl:value-of select="InputMessagePart_0/s0:Fault/s0:detail/ns6:sendFault/code/text()" />`

this is my stylesheet tag:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var s2 s0 s1 userCSharp" version="1.0" xmlns:array="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:s0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TableOp/dbo/ABCD" xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/Types/Tables/dbo" xmlns:s2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/aggschema" xmlns:s1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TypedPolling/ABC" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:userCSharp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/userCSharp" xmlns:ns6="http://thisservice.com/was/v2" xmlns:ns2="http://thisservice.com/pos/v2" >
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking (only) at your XML input, the following instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/soapenv:Fault/detail/ns3:sendFault/code" />
```

will return:

```
Actual_Code_18
```

provided that the following namespace declarations are in scope:

```
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:ns3="http://thisservice.com/was/v1"
```

Note that the `detail` element is in no namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend just using the Orchestration `xpath()` function instead of creating a whole map two get two tiny pieces of this message; like so

```
strCode= xpath(myFault, "string(/*[local-name()='Fault' and namespace-uri()='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/']/*[local-name()='detail' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='sendFault' and namespace-uri()='http://thisservice.com/was/v1']/*[local-name()='code'])");

strInfo= xpath(myFault, "string(/*[local-name()='Fault' and namespace-uri()='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/']/*[local-name()='detail' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='sendFault' and namespace-uri()='http://thisservice.com/was/v1']/*[local-name()='info'])");
```

This blog has some good information on your task, and might be helpful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/biztalknotes/archive/2013/02/12/how-to-handle-fault-message-in-biztalk-server.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The correct namespace turned out to be:
InputMessagePart_0/s1:Fault/detail/ns6:sendFault/code/text()

The problem was that I added a namespace to the detail node of the 1_1 fault.